# Import Error - No module named numpyio

Tags: python, import, numpy

Anyone know how to solve this error?

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: No module named numpyio
```

See my python code, my imports:

```
from scipy.io.numpyio import fwrite, fread
```

Can you help me??

Comment: Please format your code. You can do so by highlighting it and pressing the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 4):

This is becase the `scipy.io.numpyio` module was removed sometime aftey SciPy 0.7 (see, for example, this [thread](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2011-June/029802.html)). From the SciPy [Input/Output Cookbook page](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput) you can instead use the functions [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) and [`numpy.nadarray.tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) (see under the heading "Raw binary").

Answer (score 3):

While the `numpy.ndarray.fromfile()` allows you to specify the binary format to read (e.g. 'f' for float), the `.tofile()` function doesn't have such binary options. This is a highly inconvenient inconsistency for those of us who need to write binary files in a specific format for other software to read. Unfortunately this problem seems to be ignored by the development community as there seems to be no open ticket.

I have created a simple replacement function using the array module. The basic code goes something like this:

```
def fwrite(filename, formatstring, ndarray):
    arr = array.array(formatstring, ndarray.flatten())
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    arr.tofile(f)
    f.close()
```

So far that seems to work. Obviously this could/should be embellished with error checkes etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the [archives](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.user/28056/match=fwrite):

> The I/O functions for numpy arrays have been moved to numpy where it made, or removed when they provided duplicate functionality. Use numpy.load and numpy.save for reading writing arrays in numpy's own .npy format, loadtxt/savetxt for ascii.